# How do i getAlll While using join between 2 tables

Tags: http, jpa, ejb

RESTEASY008205: JSON Binding serialization error jakarta.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to serialize property 'coveredRegions' from shop.ShippingCompany error because ShippingCompany tableis joined with CoveredRegion in table region_company how can i solve this error in @get

```
@Path("/getAllShippingCompany")
public List<ShippingCompany> getAllShippingCompany() {
    return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM ShippingCompany c", ShippingCompany.class).getResultList();
}
```

i was expecting to get all companies but because ShippinCompany is joined with CoveredRegion its not working ,i tried the following :

```
@GET
    @Path("/getAllShippingCompany")
    public List<ShippingCompany> getAllShippingCompany() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT c FROM ShippingCompany c JOIN FETCH c.coveredRegions", ShippingCompany.class).getResultList();
    }
```

still nothing work

Comment: Better do not return the entity directly, mapping it from entity to dto/model and return dto/model.

Comment: you need to add your entity classes to the question to show how they are related

Comment: they are manyTomany related Company and Region classes

Comment: Your Error is a JSON serialization error - why do you think it has to do with the JPA mappings or query? The issue will be with the JSON mappings in the model, and how it converts that to JSON - you need to show those